# Change the timestamp format in a dataframe

Tags: timestamp

[image]I have a dataframe with timestamp like this

[image]

I would like to use random forest and for this reason I would like to convert in a different format  like this:

hour minute

[image]

is it possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H %M'))
```

If you want the result in different columns, could you try adding the following code:

```
df[['hour', 'minute']] = df['timestamp'].str.extract('(\d\d) (\d\d)')
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer! However I get an error "KeyError: 'timestamps'" don;t know why as I am kind of beginner in python

Comment: Could you put here what's the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: sure  I put a screenshot above

Comment: I edited the answer according to your clarification. Please, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks it's working, however, could it be in two columns hour and minute? As now it's all in one..thanks again

Comment: I edited it again, with a new line for two columns.